# The ring $\mathrm{End}_D(V) $ is simple if $V$ is finite dimensional.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, semi-simple-rings

> **Theorem:** Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over a division ring $D$. Then the rings $\mathrm{End}_D(V)$ and $ M_n(D^{\mathrm{o}})$ are isomorphic.
>
> **Remark:** If $D$ is a division ring, then $M_n(D)$ is a simple ring for every $n \in\mathbb N$. We infer that the ring $\mathrm{End}_D(V)$ is simple if $V$ is finite dimensional.

From  above theorem  and  remark we infer that the ring $\mathrm{End}_D(V) $ is simple if $V$ is finite dimensional.

> Is the converse actually true?
>
> Can we prove directly that $\mathrm{End}_D(V)$ is simple? (by definition)

Answer (score 1):

No.  The [full ring of linear transformations of an infinite dimensional vector space](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/ring/15/) is never simple.

It always has, at least, a nontrivial ideal made up of linear transformations with finite dimensional image.